# Can a spherical function with only $r$-dependence be an eigenstate of $L^2$ and $L_z$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, spherical-harmonics

My guess is no, because the equations for $L^2$ and $L_z$ have no $r$-dependence:

$$L^2 f_m^\ell ( \theta ,  \phi ) =  \hbar^2 \ell(\ell+1) f_m^\ell ( \theta ,  \phi )$$

$$L_z f_m^\ell ( \theta ,  \phi )=  \hbar m f_m^\ell ( \theta ,  \phi )$$

Is this the correct way of thinking about it? Or would such a function still be an eigenstate with eigenvalues both = 0?

Comment: Hydrogen ground state orbital is an eigenstate of both of these operators, and only depends on $r$.

Answer (score 6):

These are differential operators, so a function of $r$ only is effectively a constant, corresponding to the zero eigenvalues of both $L^2$ and $L_z$.